# log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.CLA - EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, sqoop, oozie, emr, amazon-emr

I am trying to run sqoop to pull data from mssql and load it to s3. I am trying to do this using Hue UI in AWS EMR, my sqoop version here is 1.4.6.

Here is the command,

```
import --connect jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/DataWarehouse --username **** --password *** --table ****_20120101 --target-dir s3://<bucket-name> --hive-drop-import-delims --escaped-by "\\"
```

I already placed the sql jdbc driver in /usr/lib/sqoop/lib/ and also placed the same jar file sqljdbc4.jar in '/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_${timestamp}/sqoop'. Everything seems fine, but i dont know why, i run the above command and the job says success but not data loaded in to s3, when i look in to the log, this is the error i am seeing,

```
    Feb 02, 2018 2:20:46 AM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.JAXBContextResolver as a provider class
Feb 02, 2018 2:20:46 AM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler as a provider class
Feb 02, 2018 2:20:46 AM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AMWebServices as a root resource class
Feb 02, 2018 2:20:47 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
Feb 02, 2018 2:20:47 AM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.JAXBContextResolver to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
Feb 02, 2018 2:20:47 AM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
Feb 02, 2018 2:20:47 AM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AMWebServices to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.CLA
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "CLA".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.CLA
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "CLA".
Intercepting System.exit(1)
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: Look like sqoop has failed (note :Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1])

Comment: I'm getting this error even though I can run Sqoop jobs just fine from the command line (without Hue).